# What are existing methods to count colored subgraph frequencies in a large colored directed graph?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I have a directed colored large network or graph. By 'color' I mean that nodes are of different categories. There are some small 3 or 4 node colored directed subgraphs. I need to know how to count their frequencies in the original large graph? can anyone link me some papers to this problem?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interested in the *graph motif problem*, in which you are given a vertex-colored graph $G$, and a multiset $M$ of $k$ colors known as a *motif*. The goal is to decide whether $G$ has a connected set of $k$ vertices whose multiset of colors agrees with the multiset $M$. Specifically, you are interested in counting all motifs.

There is a highly-optimized implementation available that solves the graph motif problem (and many of its variants). For details, see:

[Björklund, A., Kaski, P., Kowalik, L., & Lauri, J. (2015). Engineering Motif Search for Large Graphs. In ALENEX (pp. 104-118).](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611973754.10)

The software handles both directed and undirected graphs, and is oblivious to the graph structure. The conference version only shows experiments for the decision problem ("is there a motif?") and extraction ("demonstrate where this motif occurs"), but the software is indeed capable of listing all motifs.